# How do poll_wait() and wake_up_interruptible() work in sync?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a char device similar to uio. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/uio/uio.c . I see that the process is put to sleep by `poll_wait()` in poll file operation and woken up when an interrupt occurs `wake_up_interruptible()`. I couldn't understand how wait and wake_up calls are synced.

Consider this case.

`poll()` syscall is done in the userspace.

`uio_poll()` is executed.

Just before `poll_wait()`, an interrupt occurs and `wake_up_interruptible()` is done.

Now `poll_wait()` is executed.

Isn't it possible that `poll()` call  would get blocked forever in case there are no further interrupts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see that the process is put to sleep by `poll_wait()` in poll file operation ...

No, you got it wrong.

A call to `poll_wait` just sets a state of the current process into non-runnable and adds the current process into the wait queue. Both these operations are non-sleeping, so `poll_wait` returns. After that, the `poll` file operation **continues** till the end and returns a mask of the available operations.

It is the caller of the file's `poll` operation who will call `schedule()` and will put the current process into the sleep. But `schedule()` will be called only in case when returning mask of *available* operations does **not intercept** the mask of *requested* operations.

As you could see, the poll method firstly calls `poll_wait` and only then calculates the mask:

```
poll_wait(filep, &idev->wait, wait);
if (listener->event_count != atomic_read(&idev->event))
    return EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDNORM;
return 0;
```

So, in case when `wake_up_interruptible` is called before `poll_wait`, the operation returns (`EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDNORM`), and no sleeping will be performed (in case the file is polled for reading).

In case when `wake_up_interruptible` is called after `poll_wait`, it will return the process into runnable state, so `schedule()` won't put it into the sleep. After call to `schedule()`, the poll operation will be re-run, and that time it returns non-zero mask.

Comment: Thanks . So, poll_wait() does add_wait_queue(), return value of poll() acts as the condition whether or not to schedule() and then wake_up_interruptible does remove_wait_queue(). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, this analogy with regular waiting on a waitqueue is very close to polling implementation. The main difference is that a polling process could wait on **multiple waitqueues** (on multiple files) at once, so when polling terminates, the process should be removed from all waitqueues.